# PHP: Add constants to a class on runtime

Tags: php, oop, constants, class-constants

i have the following code:

```
interface ITest {
    const SIGNAL_FOO = 'foo';
}
class SomeClass extends SignalSlotObject implements ITest {
    const SIGNAL_BAR = 'bar';
}
```

`SignalSlotObject` fetches all constants beginning with 'SIGNAL_' at runtime from the class and from all interfaces it implements. That's fine and works, but my problem is:

```
$c = new SomeClass();
$c->connect(SomeClass::SIGNAL_BAR, ...); //works well
$c->connect(ITest::SIGNAL_FOO, ...);     //also works well
$c->connect(SomeClass::SIGNAL_FOO, ...); //doesn't work
```

It would be great to let the 3rd option work as well because the programmer using `SomeClass` can't know, if this signal is defined in `SomeClass` or one of it's interfaces.

My intention was to dynamically add the constants defined in the interfaces to the class on runtime but I have no hint how to add a constant on runtime to a class. I also cannot use `__set` and `__get` because they do not work on a static scope (They would work for `$c->SIGNAL_FOO` but not for `SomeClass::SIGNAL_FOO`).

Comment: You really shouldn't be defining a constant (or any variable, for that matter) from an interface. Could you change `ITest` to an abstract class and update your design accordingly?

Comment: @65Fbef05: Does PHP support multiple inheritance? If yes, i can do this.

Comment: Your classes can implement many of interfaces but can extend only one class. I'd recommend use of abstract classes for constants inheritance and interfaces for defining of methods to be implemented within class implementing the interface...

Comment: Official, It doesn't. Though depending on your design, you might be able to chain this class in from another. You could also just create a public class with no parent/child relationships to define the constants you need.

Comment: @shadyyx: The interface says: "you have to support this method and this signal". If the signal doesn't exist, it would throw an error, so that implementing the interface also includes "you can connect to this signal without an error". The programmer who uses `SomeClass` can be sure, that he can connect to this signal.

Comment: @65Fbef05: No, that is not possible, because not everything that implements `ITest` also inherits from `SignalSlotObject`, some classes may inherit from children of `SignalSlotObject`.

Comment: Years have passed, but a remark anyway. If an implementation defines it's own signals I propose a different approach. Add a `getSignals()` method to the interface which has to provide the signals known to the implementation. The OP does not describe what he's trying to accomplish. A solution that does not require manipulating classes at runtime might also work and be easier to implement and understand.